# Ruby text file parsing methodolgy

Tags: ruby, excel, parsing, csv

I've got a text file where I have a lot of lines that look like the first example and only a couple that look like the second (NB the ** are just to show the fields I'm after, they don't look like this in the actual file);

```
22034 BUBBA C BC-022 **OWL SOFTIE** <N/A> <N/A> <N/A> 470 0.00 **6** 0.00 **1** **37.95**

22489 BUBBA C BC- **BUNNY BOO BOO** <N/A> <N/A> <N/A> 470 0.00 **2** 0.00 **1** **24.95**
```

My aim is to extract the ** surrounded fields into a format (probably csv) so I can add it to as a sheet to an existing Excel spreadsheet.

My issue is I can't figure out how to extract just the data I need using gsub, split, tr, scan, match etc.

My initial thinking was as I parsed each line, I'd delete up to the 4th instance of a space (which I can't find code for), then delete/skip everything between the first < and the last >, then try and delete the next 2 fields, keep 1, delete the next and keep the remaining 2.

All of which seems a bloody hard way to get to the end result.

I don't want the exact code to solve this problem, I'm more after the methodology you would go through when you're looking at this type of problem and what tools you'd use. (strip, gsub etc)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#split`/`#join` pair to proceed:

```
a='22034 BUBBA C BC-022 **OWL SOFTIE** <N/A> <N/A> <N/A> 470 0.00 **6** 0.00 **1** **37.95**'.split
[ a[4..-10].join( ' ' ), a[-4], a[-2], a[-1] ].join ' '
# => "**OWL SOFTIE** **6** **1** **37.95**"
```

Comment: Perfect, went with this one as it was the most straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Space-delimited file, huh?  That's not the most... optimal... format.

Anyway, I would use regex to snag that `**OWL SOFTIE**` field

```
[7] pry(main)> m = s.match /BC-\d*\s(.*?)\s</
=> #<MatchData "BC-022 OWL SOFTIE <" 1:"OWL SOFTIE">

[8] pry(main)> m.captures[0]
=> "OWL SOFTIE"
```

and then `split` to grab everything else.

```
[11] pry(main)> arr = s.split[-4..-1]
=> ["6", "0.00", "1", "37.95"]
[12] pry(main)> arr.select.with_index {|x,i| i!=1 }
=> ["6", "1", "37.95"]
```

Altogether:

```
[13] pry(main)> [s.match(/BC-\d*\s(.*?)\s</).captures[0]] + s.split[-4..-1].select.with_index {|x,i| i!=1 }
=> ["OWL SOFTIE", "6", "1", "37.95"]
```

(if you have any control over that input file whatsoever, see if you can make it delimited by something other than spaces :))

Answer (score 1):

You only have one troublesome field with a variable number of words in it so start with split:

```
a = "22034 BUBBA C BC-022 OWL SOFTIE <N/A> <N/A> <N/A> 470 0.00 6 0.00 1 37.95".split
```

Then pick it apart:

```
[a[4..-10].join(' '), a[-4], a[-2], a[-1]]
```